# specifying the compiler in a gnu makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a gnu makefile template that has served me well, but when I try to specify a compiler other than the first g++ in my path, it fails.

Here's the template.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = $(INC) $(LIB) -Wall
INC = -I./ -I/usr/local/include
LIB = -L/usr/local/lib
SRCS = \
blah1.cpp
blah2.cpp

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
DEPS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.d)
PROG = myprog

$(PROG):    $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)

%.d: %.cpp
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
    $(CXX) -MM $(CXXFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$

debug: CXXFLAGS += -O0 -DDEBUG -ggdb
debug: $(PROG)

-include $(DEPS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(DEPS) $(OBJS) $(PROG)
```

When I change the compiler from g++ to something like /usr/local/bin/g++46, it still compiles with g++ (/usr/bin/g++ to be exact).  Why?

P.S.  Any criticisms with the template are welcome.  I'm not very comfortable with gnu make; I just crammed and searched the web for a day to come up with this.

Comment: I changed CC to CXX in the template above for anyone stumbling upon this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified your own rule for how to build object files, so Make uses [the default implicit rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules), which is:

```
$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c
```

Note `$(CXX)`, not `$(CC)`, which specifies the default *C* compiler.

Comment: To elaborate on that a bit, `CC` should point to some version of `gcc` or other *C* compiler, and `CXX` should be some version of `g++` or other *C++* compiler.